# create charts in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, charts

When I put this code in main.cpp it's work, but I don't want it to be in the main function. How can I  create charts in another function?

I tried to google this, and find just the `you must to put this in main.cpp`. Is C++ really so limited?

I tried everything, and they offer me only to put this code in the main function. But in C #, it was done in two clicks and everything worked as it should. Is C ++ really so limited and inoperable? I had a better opinion about this language. Although it may not be the case, but in the development environment, but I do not know the other, except this one.

```
#include "charts.h"
#include "ui_charts.h"
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSet>
#include <QtCharts/QLegend>
#include <QtCharts/QBarCategoryAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE


Charts::Charts(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Charts)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Jane");
    QBarSet *set1 = new QBarSet("John");
    QBarSet *set2 = new QBarSet("Axel");
    QBarSet *set3 = new QBarSet("Mary");
    QBarSet *set4 = new QBarSet("Samantha");

    *set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6;
    *set1 << 5 << 0 << 0 << 4 << 0 << 7;
    *set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 8 << 5;
    *set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5;
    *set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2;

    QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
    series->append(set0);
    series->append(set1);
    series->append(set2);
    series->append(set3);
    series->append(set4);


    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setTitle("Simple barchart example");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations);

    QStringList categories;
    categories << "Jan" << "Feb" << "Mar" << "Apr" << "May" << "Jun";
    QBarCategoryAxis *axisX = new QBarCategoryAxis();
    axisX->append(categories);
    chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
    series->attachAxis(axisX);

    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis();
    axisY->setRange(0,15);
    chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
    series->attachAxis(axisY);

    chart->legend()->setVisible(true);
    chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
}

Charts::~Charts()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I just have an empty screen in the page for charts.

Comment: create a Qt Widgets Application `File -> New File or Project -> Qt Widgets Application` then add your code to the Mainwindow Class

Comment: Also read up on `memory leaks`. I see you running into issues with that.

Comment: Why do I need to create a new project if I need to add charts to this one? I have already created widgets application. If I put this code in the main.cpp, all the other functionality of the program will disappear. I don't need it in MainWindow. I need the user in the program to click on a certain button and a separate window with charts opens in front of him.

Comment: @GustavLebedev Please also consider that Qt is totally overkill imho for most simple UI applications like displaying a chart, having a few windows, menus. There are much leaner, easier to use libraries out there. Do some research what fits your case best, don't simply use the 'biggest one'. Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the type of projects you would like to create.
it looks as if you have started a plain c ++ app.
QT has its own set of preconfigured projects to choose from such as :

- Qt widget applications
- Qt Quick applications

In short, a qt-based project will address your issue.   
In your case you may choose qtwidgets project , create a charts class to do all your charts related stuff, then instantiate it in the mainwindow.

Comment: I need to call not in the main window, but in another. And I already have qt widget application.

Comment: In that case. your question should be edited to : Is it possible to create many QMainWindow() instances?.  The anwser is yes you can do that. However, pay attention to the difference between the main function and the QMainwindow, the first is the entry to your application, it has to be unique while the QMainwindow is just a qwidget.a simple container of your other qwidgets.

Comment: My question is different: when i put the code in QMainWindow() code does not work. But when I put it in main.cpp - code works. But in the second case, when I start the program, I immediately open the diagrams, without the start window of my program. So, how do I make the code in the QMainWindow() work? Please look at my code is question.